# Blurry thumbnail images for video in IE (Internet Exploder)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

For some reason all of my thumbnails for my video placeholders are looking like pixelated garbage in IE but look smooth in all the real browsers.

I tried this fix:

```
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
```

...and of course IE does not even care.

Is there a solution that anyone could share? I'm at a loss and can't find anything else on the subject. Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: It would help if you specified which IE version(s) you're testing with (and which versions you need to support). Also, please provide more code: at least enough for us to see what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

**The -ms-interpolation-mode property is obsolete as of Windows Internet Explorer 9. Do not use. The -ms-interpolation-mode property was introduced in Windows Internet Explorer 7.** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530822(v=vs.85).aspx

The browsers all use pretty much the same decoding algorithm. If you were trying to use the interpolation mode that tells me you are trying to get the browsers to resize the images. Instead I recommend you actually size your images to match the size you want them rendered and reference that image instead of another size. This is a performance best practice and will either help users on smaller devices have more size appropriate images or will give you the freedom to use larger images on larger screens. Also if you are trying to expand an image beyond its dimensions pixels have to be 'guessed' at by what ever is rendering it and it will be pixelated.

Are the other browsers zoomed out and IE zoomed more in? Hit Ctrl + 0 to zoom to 100%.